# How do I iterate a list and append multiple values into a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I have a file of items with an ID, category, name, and price in each row separated by commas. I'm trying to rearrange each row so that ID, name, and price count as one value and append it to one of four keys that is determined by the category. The categories are c1, c2, c3, and c4.

The following code seems to work, but it ends up overwriting the value. When the dictionary is printed out, only one value appends to one key. I'm trying to make it so that one key may have multiple values. The problem area is in the if, elif block.

I expect to see something like {'c1': ('a b c') ('x y z'), 'c2': ('a b c') ('x y z')....

Instead I only see {'c1': 'x y z', 'c2': 'x y z'} or essentially the last value that shows up for any of the four categories in my file (which is why I'm assuming I'm overwriting rather than appending the values).

I believe I need to use .append, but what I've tried already only results in syntax errors.

Comment: post a testable file contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want is for each category in your dictionary to contain a list [List-python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Instead of initializing each element in the dictionary to None, you want to declare a new, empty list: []

Once this is in place you will be able to append each item to this with `emptyDict['cx'].append(definition)`

Something like this:

```
    emptyDict = {'c1': [], 'c2': [], 'c3': [], 'c4': []}

    for i in file:
        fields = i.split(',')
        idNum = fields[0]
        category = fields[1]  # categories are c1, c2, c3, and c4 only
        name = fields[2]
        price = fields[3]
        defintion = idNum + name + price

        if category == 'c1':
            emptyDict['c1'].append(defintion)
        elif category == 'c2':
            emptyDict['c2'].append(defintion)
        elif category == 'c3':
            emptyDict['c3'].append(defintion)
        else:
            emptyDict['c4'].append(definition)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it. I did not think of creating a new list for each category to hold multiple items, but that makes so much more sense. Also thank you for linking me the documentation.